# Apache + SVN - on browser works but SVN-client TortoiseSVN client hangs forever

Tags: apache, svn

I have set up apache + subversion and I am able to browser repo on mozilla browser using url http://localhost/repo/test/trunk/. but when I access same url on Tortoise svn client it just hangs forever.

here is the httpd.conf entry

```
<Location /repo>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath C:/amar/repo
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion repository"
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/apache/bin/pws
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I also have edited subversion access controls as below

In `C:/amar/repo/conf/svnserve.conf` enabled following lines

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

In `C:/amar/repo/conf/passwd` added new user

```
amar=amar
```

Please suggest if i am missing something. the apache + subversion + tortoise client all running on same machine. even I tried eclipse subversion client this also hangs forever.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in your config file.

Try give the anonymous access to your repository and see if repository is getting open or not.